# Customer Directive ng-repeat scope not getting in inside function Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have requirement to get the custom directive scope value.
I am trying to access the scope.cellId inside function. it's not working. Can you please anyone give solution for this.

Thanks in advance..

Here the Fiddle Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/na8udkkt/

Here is some the controller:

```
var bosAppModule = angular.module('testapp', []);

bosAppModule.controller('testCtrlr',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.layoutData =[ {layouttablecelltableid:"dsafdasfasdf"},{layouttablecelltableid:"aaaaaa"}]
}]);

bosAppModule.directive('layoutTableCellView',function($compile){

var layoutTableCellObj={};

    linkFnTableCell=function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {
        console.log("#####"+scope.cellId);
    };

    layoutTableCellObj.restrict='AE';
    layoutTableCellObj.replace='true';  
    layoutTableCellObj.scope={layoutData:'=',cellId:'@'};
    layoutTableCellObj.template="<div cell-id='tablecell.layouttablecelltableid' style='background-color:grey;height:200px;'   layout-data='layoutData' ng-repeat='tablecell in layoutData' >{{tablecell.layouttablecelltableid}}</div>";


    layoutTableCellObj.link = linkFnTableCell;

    return layoutTableCellObj;  
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrlr">
        <layout-table-cell-view> </layout-table-cell-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how the link function works. Rudi's answer shows how to get your data inside the link function. But I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve there. Can you give more details ? I've cleaned up your fiddle cause it was a bit of a mess and angular was not loading for me :

https://jsfiddle.net/6xLt4pja/1/

Directive :

```
bosAppModule.directive('layoutTableCellView', [
    function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: "<div style='background-color:grey;height:200px;' ng-repeat='tablecell in layoutData'>{{tablecell.layouttablecelltableid}}</div>",
        scope: {
          layoutData:'='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
                    console.log('SCOPE: ', scope.layoutData);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

and html :

```
<div ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrlr">
        <layout-table-cell-view layout-data="layoutData"></layout-table-cell-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are after, but if you want to access the scope values you already have declare you can access them like this in your function:

```
linkFnTableCell = function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {
    console.log("#####" + scope.cellId); // your own log

    for(var i = 0; i < scope.layoutData.length; i++){
      console.log("#####" + scope.layoutData[i].layouttablecelltableid);
    }
  };
```

This will give you all the internal id's - if you want the cellId as well the syntax will become more complex

Comment: scope.layoutData[0].layouttablecelltableid - This way getting always only one id. how to get all the id